# How to pause other videos when a selected video is playing using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, frontend

I have a list of videos, I want to pause all other videos which are not targeted when one is played.

```
<video class="demo">
 <source src="demo1.mp4">
</video>

<video class="demo">
 <source src="demo2.mp4">
</video>

<video class="demo">
 <source src="demo3.mp4">
</video>

<video class="demo">
 <source src="demo4.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: And which one is targetted? how?

Comment: I want if a user clicks any of the video to play, and then clicks another one, the previous and all other playing videos to pause and only the selected one to play.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+pause+other+video+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: hello, i made this example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rj36s8d/) you can try it

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, thanks a lot. And is there anyway that we can pause the video when it out of viewpoint!? Can intersection observer be able to do that!?